# Get count through iteration

Tags: java, count, set

```
Sunny Hot High False No
Overcast Hot High False Yes
Rainy Mild High False Yes
```

This is a sample of weather dataset.

`I need to get the count of the class label without storing them to list,array etc`.

While reading the line I should be able to get the `NO` and `YES` count. And the comparision cannot be jst no and yes . It can be any number of classes like iris dataset.

Inorder to get the `unique class label` I used set

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
String classLabel = keys.substring(keys.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
set.add(classLabel);
```

so how will I get the count of each classlabel?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: how will I get the count of each classlabel?

Comment: Please clarify what you can't store in a list/array considering that you add the `classLabel` to a `Set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does lack a bit of info and my answer is making a lot of assumptions, especially since you are putting your `classLabel` in a `Set`, I assume you can use other types of collections too, in this case a `Map`.

```
private static void weatherForecast() {

    String[] keys = {"Sunny Hot High False No", 
                     "Overcast Hot High False Yes", 
                     "Rainy Mild High False Yes"};

    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (String key : keys) {
        String[] split = key.split(" ");
        //Assume your data set is consistent with the 'classLabel' 
        //always the last field.
        String classLabel = split[split.length-1];

        if (map.containsKey(classLabel)) {
            map.put(classLabel, map.get(classLabel) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(classLabel, 1);
        }
    }

    for (String string : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(string + ": " + map.get(string));
    }    
}
```

Comment: Yes this was the same thing I was asking. Thank you radimpe